# New Latextools --output-directory and --aux-directory (Xelatex)

Tags: xetex, latextools

Recently Latex Tools updated to allow for aux and output directories to be defined.

However, for some reason, when I customise  --output-directory and --aux-directory in Latextools.sublime-settings, they do not work!

I believe this is because I am compiling using Tools> Build with > XeLatex and I cannot get Xelatex to compile from the latextools.sublime-settings file.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: So you are using MikTeX? What's the error? 'They do not work' could mean anything. Why do you believe that the cause is XeTeX?

Comment: Well apparently there is no error. It just doesn't compile anything. I believe the cause is XeTeX, because by selecting XeTeX, you would be bypassing latextools.sublime-settings correct?

Comment: Would you? I have no idea what Sublime or LaTeX Tools are. I assume an editor (something like `vim`) and an add-on to make it work nicely with LaTeX. But there's an easy way to test: try compiling with TeX or pdfTeX.

Comment: If you are using MiKTeX the output directory does not work, because it is not supported. Selectiong XeLaTeX only overwrites the engine and not the output directory. However if setting the engine does not work either there might be something wrong with your settings and you may need to create an [issue](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues) for further help.